# This trigonometric integral "has exceeded the time limit for your plan"

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I was trying to solve an integration problem-
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac {\sin(2n+1)x}{\sin(x)}{dx}$$
for all $n\ge0$

Now, putting that into Mathematica

```
n>=0
Integrate[Sin[(2n+1)x]/Sin[x],{x,0,Pi/2}]
```

It shows `$Aborted`, exceeded time limit of your plan.

What should I do to get the computation done? I can't afford to purchase their plan.

Comment: it sounds you are using wolfram alpha?  I never seen this message on Mathematica itself. This is what it gives using V  13.1  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkCdo.png) in about 1 minute time. What version of Mathematica are you using?  For the assumption, you need to write as `Integrate[Sin[(2 n + 1) x]/Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi/2}, 
 Assumptions -> n >= 0]` and not like you did.

Comment: Thank you, no I am using wolfram cloud, I am trying to learn this language but I didn't know about the _Assumptions_ command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One alternative:

```
Table[Integrate[Sin[(2 n + 1) x]/Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi/2}], {n, 0, 10}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Thank you, but can you say why `Table` command works here?

Comment: @SoumyadipMukherjee the table command has nothing to do with it. By specifying a specific value for $n$ each time, now the integration is much simpler than for a general `n`. Specific is always easier to solve than the general case.

Comment: @SoumyadipMukherjee sorry for the delayed response, but see the explanation given by Nasser :)

Answer (score 3):

Somehow trig integrals, especially those with parameters and removable discontinuities, often have tricky antiderivatives.

One can apply a standard identity:

```
Sum[Exp[2 I k x], {k, -n, n}] // FullSimplify
(*  Csc[x] Sin[x + 2 n x]  *)

Sum[Integrate[Exp[2 I k x], {x, 0, Pi/2}], {k, -n, n}] //
 AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.035712, π/2}  *)
```

The OP's integral with `Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers && n > 0` took 55 sec. on my laptop and returned an answer that was invalid for integer `n`, which probably exceeds the time limit of the OP's plan.

Comment: It would be a great help if you kindly explain me the mathematical idea behind.

Comment: ***especially those with parameters and removable discontinuities, often have tricky antiderivatives*** I think that in this is the essence of the original problem. Nice answer :)

Comment: @random Do you know [Euler's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) relating $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ to $e^{i x}$? The sum is a geometric sum, and if you convert the sum from exponential to trig form, you get your integrand. It's a well-known identity one uses in the theory of trigonometric (Fourier) series. For instance Riemann (1867) quotes Dirichlet (1830) using an integral similar to yours on pages 9–10 [here](https://www.emis.de/classics/Riemann/Trig.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yeah, i knew Euler's formula from complex numbers but not aware of Fourier series or complex analysis. And the pdf seems to be in German language but any way i will try to look into them through other sources.

Comment: @random All you really have to do is to apply the geometric sum formula to the `Sum[..]` above and afterwards convert the $e^{i\theta}$ terms you get to sine and cosine. (The paper won't be that helpful, probably. I just happened to read it a few months ago and remember running into this identity and type of integral. I just mean that it's a standard identity with a longish history — not covered in HS trig, though — but in higher applications, it's fairly common. See for instance [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel).)

Answer (score 2):

In 13.1 on Windows 10

```
Integrate[Sin[(2 n + 1) x]/Sin[x],{x, 0, Pi/2},Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]
```

> `Pi/2`

Addition. In the general case the result as @Nasser noted in his comment to the question  is as follows.

```
Integrate[Sin[(2 n + 1) x]/Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi/2}, Assumptions -> n >= 0]
```

> `(1/(4 n))E^(-I n \[Pi]) (-I - I E^(2 I n \[Pi]) -  2 I E^(I n \[Pi]) n \[Pi] Cot[n \[Pi]] -  I n PolyGamma[0, 1/2 - n/2] + I n PolyGamma[0, -(n/2)] -  I E^(2 I n \[Pi]) n PolyGamma[0, n/2] +  I E^(2 I n \[Pi]) n PolyGamma[0, (1 + n)/2] +  2 E^(I n \[Pi]) Sin[n \[Pi]])`

The above is not a closed-form expression, but an analytic expression which is hard to work with (try to substitute `n->3`). In fact, the integral under consideration is expressed in terms of other integrals.

Comment: humm. I am on V 13.1 on windows 10 and do not get your result. Screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H06vr.png)

Comment: Same, it shows $Aborted :(

Comment: @Nasser: Look at https://www.dropbox.com/s/dg8vp3v1utylkps/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202022-09-11%2013.29.24.png?dl=0 The executed nb file on demand. Try the execution on a fresh kernel and  present us the result. Do you understand me?

Comment: I did try from clean kernel. I just do not get your result. There is something different somewhere. screen shot. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNIMR.png)

Comment: @Nasser: Sorry, this is not a screen of a just executed code. Deep regard.

Comment: Please `ClearSystemCache[]` or `Clear` the system.  version 13.1 on Windows does not get `Pi/2`, the result is the same as Nasser have display.

Comment: @Nasser; That you show is the result under the assumption `Assumptions->n>=0`, not under the assumption `Assumptions->n\[Element] PositiveIntegers` (see https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3b5rz7bj7l8gi3/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202022-09-11%2013.48.45.png?dl=0).

Comment: BTW, `FullSimplify[
 1/(4 n) E^(-I n \[Pi]) (-I - I E^(2 I n \[Pi]) - 
    2 I E^(I n \[Pi]) n \[Pi] Cot[n \[Pi]] - 
    I n PolyGamma[0, 1/2 - n/2] + I n PolyGamma[0, -(n/2)] - 
    I E^(2 I n \[Pi]) n PolyGamma[0, n/2] + 
    I E^(2 I n \[Pi]) n PolyGamma[0, (1 + n)/2] + 
    2 E^(I n \[Pi]) Sin[n \[Pi]]), 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]` results in `ComplexInfinity`.

Comment: Also `Limit[1/(4 n)
   E^(-I n \[Pi]) (-I - I E^(2 I n \[Pi]) - 
    2 I E^(I n \[Pi]) n \[Pi] Cot[n \[Pi]] - 
    I n PolyGamma[0, 1/2 - n/2] + I n PolyGamma[0, -(n/2)] - 
    I E^(2 I n \[Pi]) n PolyGamma[0, n/2] + 
    I E^(2 I n \[Pi]) n PolyGamma[0, (1 + n)/2] + 
    2 E^(I n \[Pi]) Sin[n \[Pi]]), n -> k, 
 Assumptions -> k \[Element] PositiveIntegers]` produces `Indeterminate` instead of `Pi/2`.

Answer (score 2):

TrigFactor and TrigReduce the integrand to see a systematic, FourierCos like expansion depending on n.

```
$Assumptions = Element[n, Integers] && n > 0;
f = Sin[(2 n + 1) x]/Sin[x];

tab = Table[{n, f}, {n, 1, 6}] // TrigFactor // TrigReduce // 
  TableForm

(*   {{1, 1 + 2 Cos[2 x]}, 
      {2, 1 + 2 Cos[2 x] + 2 Cos[4 x]}, 
      {3, 1 + 2 Cos[2 x] + 2 Cos[4 x] + 2 Cos[6 x]}, 
      {4, 1 + 2 Cos[2 x] + 2 Cos[4 x] + 2 Cos[6 x] + 2 Cos[8 x]}, 
      {5, 1 + 2 Cos[2 x] + 2 Cos[4 x] + 2 Cos[6 x] + 2 Cos[8 x] + 2 Cos[10 x]}, 
      {6, 1 + 2 Cos[2 x] + 2 Cos[4 x] + 2 Cos[6 x] + 2 Cos[8 x] + 2 Cos[10 x] + 2 Cos[12 x]}}   *)
```

Since the integrals over Cos are zero, only integral over integrand == 1 remains, yielding Pi/2.

```
Integrate[2 Cos[2 n x], {x, 0, Pi/2}]    (*   0   *)
```